# Comparación de fechas en DJANGO

Tags: django, django-models, djangorestframework, django-views

Estoy trabajando con django, y quiero poner una condición en mi archivo views.py, quiero que me compare 2 horas y que no permita que la primera (start) sea mayor que la segunda (end), sin embargo no me permite ya que me sale el siguiente error : Exception `Type:  MultiValueDictKeyError`

Aqui esta mi archivo views:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.generics import CreateAPIView
from AsesorSch.models import Aschedule, Abreak
from .serializers import AsesorBrkSerializers

class AsesorBrCreateApiView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = AsesorBrkSerializers

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.data["Abreak.start"] > request.data["Abreak.end"]:
            return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return Response("Fecha no valida")
```

Mi archivo serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from AsesorSch.models import Abreak

class AsesorBrkSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Abreak
        fields = (
            'id',
            'start',
            'end',
            'idSch'
        )
```

Mi archivo models.py:

```
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.
from AsesorData.models import residency_advisor
from scheduleStudent.models import Day

class Abreak(models.Model):
    start = models.TimeField()
    end = models.TimeField()
    idSch = models.ForeignKey(Aschedule, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.idSch}: DESCANSO ENTRE {self.start} - {self.end}'
```

Si pueden ayudarme lo agradecería mucho!

Comment: Lo haces bien, solo quita el "Abreak" y solo pon los campos, así: `['start']`

Comment: Muchas gracias!, funciono totalmente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal como el usuario  Julio Cesar comento, la respuesta es simplemente modificar la variables `"Abreak.start"` y `"Abreak.end"` quedando solo `start` y `end`, todo esto en el archivo views.py:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.generics import CreateAPIView
from AsesorSch.models import Aschedule, Abreak
from .serializers import AsesorBrkSerializers

class AsesorBrCreateApiView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = AsesorBrkSerializers

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.data["start"] > request.data["end"]:  #<- en esta linea fue el cambio
            return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return Response("Fecha no valida")
```